# JS file has wrong type when run on Server (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jsp

Im still new to Angular and what I'm trying to do is to create an angular controller in a separate js file and map it with my jsp file. The problem is that I cannot get angular work. Though it works just fine if I include controller script into the jsp file itself. Somehow the server cannot find those script files and it throws 404 error. Nevertheless I specify the files paths correctly in my opinion.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

And this is my home.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html ng-app="vApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>

    <script type="application/javascript"           src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/angular/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/angular/UsersController.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>This is the homepage!</p>

    <div ng-controller="Hello as first">
        <h1>Supposed to be cool</h1>
        <p>The ID is {{first.id}}</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="first.content">
        <p>The content is {{first.content}}</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Might this type thingy be a problem? if not, why is it impossible to find these files?

Thanx in advance.

**EDIT**
Server side code:
dispatcher-servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="vermilion.calendar.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="vermilion.calendar.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="vermilion.calendar.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="vermilion.calendar.dao" />


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location" value="resources/jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="sessionFactory.hibernateProperties">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">${hibernate.transaction.factory_class}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>


</bean>
```

HomeController:

```
package vermilion.calendar.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import vermilion.calendar.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

@Qualifier("userService")
@Autowired
public UserService userService;




@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
    //return "login";
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listUsers() {

    return  "home";
}

}
```

project structure:
[image]

Comment: You are getting a 404 response, which is likely returnging an HTML document telling you that (you can see in that network tab Response is `404 Not Found`). Your issue is server side and has nothing to do with Javascript... whether it be an image, a javascript file, etc. that file is not being served from that path.

Comment: What webserver are you running? It is sending your JS files with a text/html MIME type instead of application/javascript

Comment: Like @rgthree said, the `html` type is that of your 404 page, so there is an issue with your path. `WEB-INF/angular/app.js` is pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: Include your server side code for a chance to get an answer.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope that is what's needed to understand better the problem. I suspect that something is wrong with the script path, but that is weird as it is a right path to the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't found any reasonable solution to this problem, I ended up creating a new project, but this time I created a simpele web dynamic project (not maven), converted to maven later. Also added a

```
<welcome-file>
```

to the web.xml as well as I used

`<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vermilion</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`.

instead of

`<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vermilion</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

I'm not sure which of these actions did the job and what actually was wrong, but now it works with angular controllers.

Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is your problem with path.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/angular/app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="WEB-INF/angular/UsersController.js"></script>
```

You can use ${pageContext.request.contextPath} to get root path of your application.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/angular/app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/angular/UsersController.js"></script>
```

or use JSTL [c:url](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm).

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/WEB-INF/angular/app.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/WEB-INF/angular/UsersController.js'/>"></script>
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but, unfortunately, neither of these options works for me :(